# How to delete data in hashmap

Tags: java, android

In my case I will have 450 data in 1 sec, then I wrap it every 50 data because I only need 50 data, but 400 data still save in temporary even I clear the hashmap data. So how to delete all data in hashmap?

```
Date date = new Date();
leftDataDict.put(String.valueOf(formatter.format(date)),Arrays.toString(l_data_double_arr));

if (leftDataDict.size() == 50) {
    leftDataDictCon.clear();
    leftDataDictCon.putAll(leftDataDict);
    sendToFirebase(leftDataDictCon, "Left_Insole");
    leftDataDict.clear();
}
```

Comment: You already use `clear()` which will _"delete all data in hashmap"_. It is unclear what you're really asking. Please provide a [mre] and clearly explain the problem.

Comment: yes, but when I save the data to firebase the total data is still 450 data. then firebase will delete it manually.

Comment: So the problem is with Firebase, not with the hashmap in Java?

Comment: I think the problem is in Java. because if I see from logcat if data already clear I will get 1 data in a sec. but now I get data more data 1 in 1 sec

Comment: 2022-05-22 17:26:36.753 onMessageReceived: 50
2022-05-22 17:26:37.083 onMessageReceived: 50
2022-05-22 17:26:37.132 onMessageReceived: 50
2022-05-22 17:26:37.181 onMessageReceived: 50
2022-05-22 17:26:37.230 onMessageReceived: 50
2022-05-22 17:26:37.561 onMessageReceived: 50
2022-05-22 17:26:37.610 onMessageReceived: 50
2022-05-22 17:26:37.660 onMessageReceived: 50
2022-05-22 17:26:37.709 onMessageReceived: 50
2022-05-22 17:26:38.040 onMessageReceived: 50